# In .NET Core: how to read a json response as list

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient

I need help to read a Json response with no item's list like a list, using `HttpClient`.

In particular I want to read this object like a list:

```
{
    "0": {
        "cik_str": 320193,
        "ticker": "AAPL",
        "title": "Apple Inc."
    },
    "1": {
        "cik_str": 789019,
        "ticker": "MSFT",
        "title": "MICROSOFT CORP"
    },
    "2": {
        "cik_str": 1067983,
        "ticker": "BRK-B",
        "title": "BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY INC"
    }
}
```

The full response is in here: [www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers.json](https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers.json)

I need a code example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things

1. Load your Jason from server

```cs
var url = "https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers.json";
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: Can not connect with the server {response.StatusCode}");
    return;
}
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

2. Deserialize your JSON

- add the following class to your project

```cs
public class CompanyTickers
{
    [JsonPropertyName("cik_str")]
    public int Cik{ get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("ticker")]
    public string Ticker { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonPropertyName("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

- DeSerialize and use your results

```cs
var companyTickers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, CompanyTickers>>(json);
foreach(var company in companyTickers.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{company.Cik} {company.Ticker} {company.Title}");
}
```

Comment: Thx my good sir, I'll try that.